# gtsummary's tbl_regression() returning odd result

Tags: gtsummary

I'm using gtsummary::tbl_regression to format the output of the following code:

```
dat.mi <- import(here("temp", "adTurn_mi.rds"))

fit1 <- glm(quit ~ sex + age + race + education + experience + tenure_sr + 
              salary + anymc + catcap + medi + nonpro + rural, 
            family = 'binomial', 
            weights = svy_weight, 
            data = complete(dat.mi)
            ) |> 
  tbl_regression(exponentiate = TRUE)
```

dat.mi is MICE data (unfortunately I can't provide a truly reproducible example as the data is confidential), but is completed in the call to the glm() function. tbl_regression formats everything beautifully, with the exception of one line, and I cannot figure out what that one line is doing or how to fix it. Instead of returning an exponentiated coeficient, it returns a string of numbers separated by commas (please see the Masters degree line in the attached image). Is this a known issue with a similarly known and easy fix? Or am I just really good at breaking stuff?

[image: tbl_regression output]

Comment: This is an artifact of your model, rather than an issue with `tbl_regression()`. You odds ratio (and associated confidence intervals) are HUGE. To me, this suggests an issue with the model estimation. If you feel your model is well estimated, you can modify the way the estimates are rounded/styled, you can pass a difference rounding function to `tbl_regression(estimate_fun=)`.

Comment: I figured. These data are all over the shop. Okay. Thank you so much for both your package and your speedy answer!